# Conservation of Kinetic energy in splitting

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

If a stationary mass $M$ explodes into 2 masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ with velocity $v_1 $and $v_2$ respectively releasing no energy in any other form like sound and heat.
Then I've read that-
intial k.E = Final K.E
i.e
$$0 = \frac{1}{2}m_1(v_1)^2+ \frac{1}{2}m_2(v_2)^2 $$
But i am confused that wont't the sum of final K.E will be equal to energy of explosion since its the energy of explosion that results in giving velocities to the particles and their K.E.

Comment: *But i am confused that won't the sum of final K.E will be equal to energy of explosion since its the energy of explosion $\dots$* - I agree. It is momentum which is conserved in this sort of situation.

Comment: There is some stored energy, at the start, that is going be the energy of explosion. It is some form of potential energy. $$\text{CoE}:\quad\sum E_i=\sum E_f\quad\implies\quad PE+0=0+KE$$

Comment: Your equation implies that zero is the sum of two non-negative numbers (in fact, two positive numbers since v1 and v2 are presumably not zero). Your equation is unphysical.

Answer (score 0):

Going off naturallyInconsistent’s thought in the comments, there needs to be some potential/stored energy at the beginning that will give the particles their kinetic energy. An example would maybe be a ballon so full of water that it explodes, breaking into many rubber bits. This would be EPE, elastic potential energy stored.

The right conservation formula is
$$\text{P.E} = \frac{1}{2} (m_1v_1^2 +m_2v_2^2)$$ for some P.E$>0$. Furthermore, using momentum conservation $$0=m_1v_1 +m_2v_2$$, which is set to $0$ because the $M$ particle was at rest, we can find the relative velocities of particles. E.g, if we say the initial potential energy is equal to $P$,we can form an equation for $v_2$:
$$P= \frac{1}{2}\big (\frac{m_2^2v_2^2}{m_1} +m_2v_2^2\big)$$
Solving this will give you $v_2 $and it will depend on the masses and the intial potential energy $P$.

Comment: Momentum will be conserved (=0) but kinetic energy comes from energy of explosion.

Comment: This is consistent with what I am saying.

Comment: It is.  My comment was (meant to be) to the original question, not to your response.

Comment: Although "potential energy" might be a slightly confusing name for P

Comment: Great suggestion (edited to include this). @Amit Rai, please mark as completed if you are satisfied.